# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS' Expecting ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.insertdata (@t DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2 (*columns*)
        SELECT * 
        FROM table1
        WHERE CAST(date AS DATE) = CAST(@t AS DATE);
END
```

I followed the how to create the function and this function won't return any value just only will update the table.

The error shown is:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

When I hovered at the error there states

> Incorrect syntax near 'AS'. Expecting ID.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: My spider sense is telling me something is wrong with the code you *didn't* include in the post...

Comment: What this function will _RETURNS_ before the `AS` keyword?

Comment: _Functions_ should return something, since this is not return anything you should use _Stored Procedure_ instead.

Comment: A function is probably the wrong tool for insert...select if you are not returning anything. You should probably create a stored procedure instead.

Comment: okay. Thank you guys It help me a lot. I thought it same as postgres that create function in the sql server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `Stored Procedure`, since in any programming language a `Function` should always **return** a value, and since your code does not, you should use a `Stored procedure` instead.

You get this error because the function needs te return a value, I suggest you use a stored procedure instead.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertdata (@t DATETIME)-- Why you are using DATETIME here
AS
    INSERT INTO table2 (*columns*)
        SELECT * 
        FROM table1
        WHERE CAST(date AS DATE) = CAST(@t AS DATE);--and cast it to DATE here
GO
```

A beside note, I don't think you need to pass `@t` variable as `DATETIME` datatype and then cast it to `DATE`, just declare it as `DATE` then you don't need to cast it.

So your stored procedure would be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertdata (@t DATE)
AS
    INSERT INTO table2 (*columns*)
        SELECT * 
        FROM table1
        WHERE CAST(date AS DATE) = @t;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You did't set the return for your function.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.insertdata(@t datetime)
RETURNS @returnTable TABLE 
( Field DECIMAL(38,6) null, Field2 DECIMAL(38,6) null )
AS
BEGIN
....
END
```

Comment: But my function only just want to update and insert data into my table2

Comment: then you should go with store procedure

Comment: Function always return something